# Android: Bluetooth - Programmatically accept all file transfers

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was wondering if there was a way to accept every incoming Bluetooth file transfers on the android without tapping on "Yes I agree to accept the incoming file"

So, whenever someone sends my android device with a file, I do not need to agree/accept. It will automatically receive it.

Comment: AFAIK stock Android OS does not support Bluetooth file transfer. What kind of device are you using? Do you use some special app to do Bt file transfer?

Comment: I am writing my own app to do so, there are a couple of BT file transfer apps on the market.